# Get only photo from flickr using id to display in app

Tags: flickr

I checked flickr api documents.Little bit confusing I feel. Which api should be used to display image in mobile app (Only photo).Photo id stroing in our server.Making request with this photo id we want image to dsiplay.

Answer (score 0):

Given the ID, you can use [flickr.photos.getSizes](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getSizes.html) to retrieve the various URLs for the various versions of the image that are available.